# Excel ListObject with dependent combobox using the same DataSet and DataTable

Tags: winforms, excel, vsto

In Excel 2007 using VSTO, if I have a `ListObject` using a SQL table `DataSet` with the below example columns:

```
[Year],[Month],[Unit],[Site]
```

How can you get a `combobox` to use `SELECT DISTINCT [Year]` from the same `DataSet`? as its data source and then have the `ListObject` depend on the selected year in the `combobox`?

It seems simple enough but I'm not very well versed on the correct way to use VSTO and the data sets, binding sources, table adapters and so on...

any help or useful articles would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out now using the `DataSet` designer and the below steps.

1. Right clicking my `DataTable` which in my case is called `Units`.
2. Selecting `Add Query`
3. Selecting `Use SQL Statements`
4. Selecting `SELECT which returns rows`
5. Added this query into the text box `SELECT DISTINCT [Year] FROM [Units] ORDER BY DESC`
6. Un-checking the `Fill a DataTable` option and changing the `Return a DataTable` name to `GetDataByDistinctYear`
7. Following the above process again but using this SQL Statement `SELECT [Year],[Month],[Unit],[Site] FROM [Units] WHERE [Year] = @Year`
8. Then changing the name of both the fill and return datatable options to `FillByYear` and `GetDataByYear`
9. This added new queries to my `UnitsTableAdapter`.
10. Then in the code .vb file for my WorkSheet I added the below code:

```vb
Private Sub Sheet1_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
...
YearComboBox.DataSource = UnitsTableAdapter.GetDataByDistinctYear()

End Sub

Private Sub YearComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles YearComboBox.SelectedValueChanged

Me.UnitsTableAdapter.FillDataByYear(Me.UnitsDataSet.Units, YearComboBox.SelectedValue)

End Sub
```

I hope someone finds this useful at least.

Thanks